# Powershell - How can I get a directory listing w/o subfiles and only list top 5 files?

Tags: powershell

I understand the `dir` (Get-ChildItem) and `Sort-Object` command-lets, but I need to output to a file the top **x** files.

For example, if I sort by `LastWriteTime`, how can I limit the output to only the top 5 files?

(No need to access sub-files.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want:

```
ls | ?{! $_.psiscontainer} | sort -property lastwritetime | select -first 5
```

Answer (score 1):

with PS3:

```
   PS III> ls -file | sort lastwritetime | select -first 5
```

another option:

```
   PS III> (ls -file | sort lastwritetime)[0..4]
```